# How to configure odoo-connector to listen on on_record_create event?

Tags: python, events, event-handling, odoo-10

Am using odoo10. In the models/models.py file I have the following:

```
from connector.event import on_record_create

@on_record_create
def on_create_trigger(session, model_name, record_id, vals):
    print model_name
```

I have installed the queue_job module and the connector module without errors. But, when I create a new user and hit the save button doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my code out of the models module in a file called events.py, then in the **init**.py added an import for events. Then changed the import in the events.py file, that was wrong.
It was as follows:

### **init**.py

```
from . import controllers
from . import models
import events
```

### events.py

```
from odoo.addons.connector.event import on_record_create

@on_record_create()
def procesa_creacion_de_usuarios(session, model_name, record_id, vals):
  print session
  print model_name
  print record_id
```

And it worked!!